# UK visa: my partner doesn't want to submit his bank statement

Tags: visas, uk

My boyfriend is inviting me to visit him in the UK. He's originally from our country and migrated there almost 20 years ago. He's now a citizen. He will pay for my roundtrip tickets, accommodation and I will only pay for the visa application here.

We have already completed all the requirements we think we need. I have my passport, certificate of employment, bank statements, payslip etc. He also gave everything above to me already EXCEPT for his bank statements. He said it would not be required on his end. I know he earns a lot there according to his payslips and P60, but I really do think that his bank statements are required. What do you think? Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How well do you know him? Sometimes couples don't want to share financial details with each other, but you need to be very confident that he is trustworthy when you are going to travel a long distance to a place where you don't know anyone but him. People are often exploited by someone pretending to be in a relationship with them.

Comment: If your application states that you are relying on him to cover all or part of the costs of your visit, it would be normal practice for him to provide bank statements in support. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab He doesn’t necessarily have to provide statements for every bank account he has, eg he could provide statements for the account showing his salary receipt and a savings account showing he has sufficient funds available (if the balance in the current account isn’t enough).

Comment: @user16259 Thanks for the response and for your concern about my safety. He's the cousin of my work colleague of 5 years. I have already met his remaining family here and he already met mine. I'm like 99% sure that we need to show his bank statements :(

Comment: @Traveller Thank you so much! Have you heard from anyone a case like this where the sponsor didnt provide bank statements? This is  a bit weird.

Comment: @j08 I’ve seen refusals where the applicant didn’t provide statements, I don’t recall anything similar re sponsors. If you don’t have a previous travel history, the stronger the evidence provided the better the chance of success. Payslips and P60 show his income, not whether he has sufficient resources to fulfil his financial responsibilities to you as a sponsor. I suggest you ask him to read s2 of https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Comment: @j08 Also https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF#page19

Answer (score -4):

As for my experience it's not necessary for your bf to send the bank statements ..just ask him the take a picture of one of his card.just include like utility bill..what they need is the proof that he is really a resident there..hope it will help.